# Why cant I iterate over Object with for Each

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate over an object with the forEach array method.

```
var obj = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3};
[].forEach.call(obj, function(n, key) {
    console.log(key, n)
})
```

should Print

a:1

b:2

c:3

This doesn't work as it returns undefined in the debugger even when I artificially add a length property to the obj

```
obj.length = 3;
```

How do I make this object array like so i can call array method like foreach on the object. I am aware there are other ways to iterate over an object was just wondering what I was doing wrong in this scenario.

Comment: Because `Array.forEach` is meant for arrays, or at least to be called on iterable array-like objects with a length. Just use a `for-in` loop instead.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) { console.log( key, obj[key]); }); `

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: `forEach` will only access numeric properties of the array(-like object). `'a'` is not numeric. So I guess the answer to your question is "you can't" ?

Comment: got it, numeric properties answers my question

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will only work on arrays and not on objects. You could use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to loop over the object's own enumerable properties:

```
var obj = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```